# Save the browser instance in process.env

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using an api with express. I have put the launch of the browser as middleware.

```
// app.js

require('dotenv').config();
require('./config/puppeteer');
...
const app = express();
...
```

In puppeter configuration to launch the browser, I use `puppeteer.launch([options])` and then save the object in `porcess.env.BROWSER`

```
// config/puppeteer.js

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function runBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true,
        slowMo: 10,
    });;
    process.env.BROWSER = JSON.stringify(browser);
})();
```

But when I make `JSON.stringify` from the browser I get the following error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56296/devtools/browser/3069f03b-0a46-4d59-b378-c38e650cba65
(node:17192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Browser'
    |     property '_defaultContext' -> object with constructor 'BrowserContext'
    --- property '_browser' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at runBrowser (C:\Users\jcortes\devs\nodejs\scraper\config\puppeteer.js:9:32)
```

Comment: Hi Juan, I may be wrong but I just tried to double check the dotenv package (if that's what you're using for env) and I don't think you can set a new .env as you have. You might be able to test this if you just turn ```process.env.BROWSER``` to ```const test``` and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is launch the browser in the `config/puppeteer.js` file with `runBrowser()`. Once launched, I save the address of the websocket to later connect to the same instance (`puppeteer.connect()`). In this way I can use the same browser and every time a request arrives it creates a new page.

```
// config/puppeteer.js

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function runBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true,
        slowMo: 10
    });
    process.env.WSENDPOINT = browser.wsEndpoint();
})();

...
```

```
// app.js

require('dotenv').config();
require('./config/puppeteer');
...
const app = express();
...
```